# cisco vpn conflicting with xampp/localhost?

Tags: xampp, localhost

Xampp and localhost had been working fine, but something happened that has made localhost (or 127.0.0.1 url) no longer work.

Possible Culprit: I installed Cisco AnyConnect recently. I stopped the Cisco AnyConnect service to no avail. Uninstalling it wont fix it, because I fear it has made some permanent changes. Plus I do need the software. However, I have stopped the service.

Another funny thing I notice: Apache has two pids and two ports in the XAMPP control panel. However, it was probably that way even when it was working earlier, but I could be wrong.

Any other suggestions?

I have already quit Skype etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing to do will be to confirm the port usage of your computer. If you are using Windows, then run this in command prompt:
"netstat -O"
this will give us an insight into the next decision. From your question, I suspect that you use port 80 for your Xampp.
If the port usage shows that something  else is using the port, why not try to configure Xampp to use a different port for troubleshooting purposes

Comment: It's not using port 80. Xampp Control Panel shows 1337, 7331 as the ports. What's weird is if I run localhost:1337 or localhost:1337/somestaticwebsite, it does work. However, localhost or localhost/somestaticwebsite does not. Dynamic websites (like WP) don't work irrespective of whether I add port numbers in the URLS or not.